CSV to HTML JS, formatting the link using a variable
Using the source code from GitHub https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#readme to parse a CSV to HTML nicely searchable formatted column.
Off the shelf works splendidly, thank you Derek.
Edited to my own source and adapting to suit with additional columns to hyperlink.
Can't seem to edit the hyperlink format_link so that my hyperlinks go to the page in a new tab I want them to.  The original source data has the fields configured as full http://url format so there was no need for additional formatting within the Script.  Me on the other hand my CSV has only an IP address as a number eg 192.168.0.10.
This is the original code, I have added the //Comment to help me talk myself through changes and additions I am making for my own personalisation
function format_link(link) {
            if (link)
                return "<a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>" + link +  "</a>"; //Add http wrapper and port to accommodate our requirements.
            else return "";
}

I have tried all sorts of variations of adding " or ' into the return string, but I either break it entirely or get no different results.
At present the original code without editing gives a link in a New Tab of http://localhost/sourcefolder/192.168.0.10 This obvs is not correct as there is no IP address or reference in the source folder.
What I want it to do is link the text contained in the specified columns, in my case 8 and 9 set as an array and return when clicked a new tab with the following example url:
http://192.168.0.10:8080
So content from csv file is 192.168.0.10 format_link needs to convert it to http://192.168.0.10:8080 and land it in a new Tabs as it does at present.  I am thinking a synatx formatting issue?
I feel like I am so close and want to get this right before moving on to adding in the ping code testing that I am planning on using this all for.  Based on this video I found.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivB1SpOy4Qg. I have already adapted that to include a secondary IP column as well as making and then I can work on graphics and prettifying and then the database prettiness of it all comes later.

To mix quotes and use + to concatenate is very error prone. If you insist, it could be done like this, where the single quotes are used for the JavaScript and the conventional HTML double quotes are used for the attributes:
'<a target="_blank" href="http://' + link + ':8080">' + link + '</a>';

To safely concatenate strings, you can use a more modern and simpler method using template literals and a ternary
const format_link = (link) => link ? `<a href="http://${link}:8080" target="_blank">${link}</a>` : '':


A last alternative is to use the methods made to do what you want. They are somewhat slower but very safe

URL constructor
createElement


const format_link = (link) => {
  if (!link) return ""; // bail out
  const url = new URL('http://000.000.000.000:8080'); // dummy IP in constructor to avoid string concatenation
  url.hostname = link; // replace the 000.000.000.000 with the passed IP address
  // Alternative: Create the URL using template literals
  // const url = new URL(`http://${link}:8080`);
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.target = '_blank';
  anchor.href = url.toString()      
  anchor.textContent = link;
  return anchor;
};

Note that the above function will return an anchor object, and you will need container.appendChild(format_link(ipaddress)) to add it to the document:


link = "123.123.123.123"
const format_link = (link) => {
  if (!link) return ""; // bail out
  const url = new URL('http://000.000.000.000:8080'); // dummy IP in constructor to avoid string concatenation
  url.hostname = link;
  // Alternative: Create the URL using template literals
  //const url = new URL(`http://${link}:8080`);
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.target = '_blank';
  anchor.href = url.toString()
  anchor.textContent = link;
  return anchor;
};
document.body.appendChild(format_link(link))




Hi Gadot appreciate the input, I am really not a super knowledgeable coder.  But I know enough to know strip it out tidy it up, all helps for the running and execution of the code.
So help me out, can you post your entire replacement code with your suggestion inserted?  I am playing here and the variations of position and subsitution are not working for me.
I also note you are using ${link} where the original is using +link+.  Variation deliberate, concerned about referencing in other script elements.

The code I posted is a one to one replacement of your function. - I am using template literals to embed the link in the string.

HI Godot, the vote was certainly not from me.  I have not enough credits to vote on anything yet.  I did try and upvote it.

@StevenAbbott I have given you 3 versions - I hope they are enlightening.

In the end I discovered other code that I had used in another PHP related query and used that to form the below alternative code which answers my question adding in the Href functionality desired.
function format_link(link) {
        if (link)
           return "<a target='_blank' href=\"http://" + link + ":8080\">" + link + "</a>";
        else return "";
    }


Your solution is very fragile since you mix single and double quotes.
